# Add query string or GUiD to the end of URL on page load using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, guid

I found an example on how to create a GUID with Javascript, but how would I get the current page URL and append the GUID to it using jQuery or Javascript.

```
  function S4() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }

    // then to call it, plus stitch in '4' in the third group
    guid = (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-4" + S4().substr(0, 3) + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
    //alert(guid);
```

I tried window.location = window.location + '?guid=' + guid, but that just redirected the page over and over again while appending the guid to the end of the URL.

I just need to append the GUID to the end of the URL once on page load. 
How would I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to check whether the location already has a guid, if it is not there then reload the page.

```
var lc = window.location;
if(!(/\?guid=/.test(lc))) {
    window.location = window.location + '?guid=' + guid
}
```